# The delegate in this app is not being set

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have an app with two view controllers... ViewController and CollectionViewController. I have filter functions in the viewController that perform color filters on an image loaded into this view controller. The CollectionViewController contains a collection view that acts as a horizontal scrolling menu with cells, that when pressed, are supposed to call the filter functions in ViewController. The storyboard has a show segue with ID "FilterSegue"

I got it to work with Notification Centers but I wanted to try to get it to work with protocols and delegates to learn about the methods. I received some suggestions, but have been unable to get the delegate to set despite numerous attempts.
Here is the code:

**ViewController:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, FilterDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "FilterSegue" {

            let destvc = segue.destinationViewController as! CollectionViewController 
            destvc.filterDelegate = self

        }
    }


    func onRedFilter() {

        // some code

    }

    func onGreenFilter() {

        // some code

    }


    func onBlueFilter() {

        // some code

    }

    func onUnfiltered() {

        // some code

    }

}
```

**CollectionViewController:**

```
import UIKit

//Protocols for filter functions called by the filter menu collection view custom cells.
protocol FilterDelegate: class {
    func onRedFilter()
    func onGreenFilter()
    func onBlueFilter()
    func onUnfiltered()
}

class CollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    let reuseIdentifier = "FilterCell"

    var filterDelegate: FilterDelegate? = nil


    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    // Filter labels for custom filter menu cells.
    var tableData:[String] = ["Red Filter",
                              "Green Filter",
                              "Blue Filter",
                              "Unfilter",
                              "New Filter 1",
                              "New Filter 2"]

    // Filter images for custom filter menu cells.
    var tableImages: [String] = ["waterfallred.png",
                                 "waterfallgreen.png",
                                 "waterfallblue.png",
                                 "waterfall.png",
                                 "waterfall.png",
                                 "waterfall.png"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


        // Set up collectionView for the filters.

        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 120, height: 80)

        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)

        collectionView!.registerClass(colvwCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        collectionView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        self.view.addSubview(collectionView!)

    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    // Set uo required methods for collection view.
    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

        return 1

    }


    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return tableData.count

    }


    // Method for custom collection view cell texts and images.
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell: colvwCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! colvwCell

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

        cell.lblCell.text = tableData[indexPath.row]
        cell.imgCell.image = UIImage(named: tableImages[indexPath.row])

        return cell

    }


    // Method for calling functions upon pressing custom filter menu collection view cells. In this case, the filter functions in the main view controller are called using notifications.

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        print("Cell \(indexPath.row) selected")

        guard let filterDelegate = filterDelegate else {
            print("Filter delegate wasn't set!")
            return
        }

        switch indexPath.row {

            case 0:
                filterDelegate.onRedFilter()
            case 1:
                filterDelegate.onGreenFilter()
            case 2:
                filterDelegate.onBlueFilter()
            case 3:
                filterDelegate.onUnfiltered()
            default:
                print("No available filter.")

        }

    }

}
```

The guard statement returns "Filter delegate wasn't set!" on any depressed cell on the collection view menu.

Comment: Let's check the basics. Put a breakpoint on the line `destvc.filterDelegate = self`. Is it getting executed?

Comment: No, it is not being executed.

Comment: So the problem is that your segue is not in fact called `"FilterSegue"`.

Comment: I am not sure the prepareForSegue is being executed at all. I placed breakpoints at three points with no response.

Comment: That's possible too. But according to you, the collection view controller is appearing _somehow_.

Comment: The collectionview controller is appearing and was appearing before I implemented the protocols and delegates.

Comment: "FilterSegue " is the ID I gave the segue on the storyboard.

Comment: But you have to explain why `prepareForSegue` is not being called. It is not being called because the collection view controller is not the destination of a segue from ViewController that gets triggered in order to show the collection view. Because if it were, it _would_ be called.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

```
protocol FilterDelegate: class {
func onRedFilter()
----
}
```

try this

```
protocol FilterDelegate {
    func onRedFilter()
    ----
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea but still doesn't set the delegate.

Comment: Can someone explain to me why someone would down vote the question? I read the material pertaining to posting questions, checked previous questions of the same general time before I asked, and made sure I followed the format. I think my grammar is reasonable and I provided code edited down to the essentials. This makes no sense to me. I am a new Swift programmer and need a bit of help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer...

I realized that the segue wasn't being set because it was trying to instantiate another collection view controller with the segue. I removed the prepareForSegue altogether and the segue from the storyboard.
I have a button called onFilter2 on the main view controller that instantiates the collection view in a container on a press (calls a function showFilterMenu to show the filter menu) and then hides it on a second press (hideFilterMenu). The showFilterMenu function is where the colectionviewcontroller is instantiated. So, I set the delegate in this function. It took one line of code.

Here is the function executed upon pressing the filter button with the correct call of the delegate.

```
  // New onFilter button action that shows/hides the filter collection view scroll bar on main view controller.
    @IBAction func onFilter2(sender: UIButton) {

        if filterButtonOn == true {

            if (sender.selected) {

                hideFilterMenu()
                editButton.selected = false
                sender.selected = false

            } else {

                showFilterMenu()
                sender.selected = true
                hideSliderMenu()
                editButton.selected = false


                //Reset color sliders to initial values.
                redHorizontalSlider?.setValue(0, animated: false)
                greenHorizontalSlider?.setValue(0.0, animated: false)
                blueHorizontalSlider?.setValue(0.0, animated: false)

                // Set initial values for color indicators.
                redSliderIndicator.text = "0.00"
                greenSliderIndicator.text = "0.00"
                blueSliderIndicator.text = "0.00"

            }

        }

    }


    // Shows the filter menu scrolling bar in container view upon request.
    func showFilterMenu() {

        let newViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FilterCollectionView") as! CollectionViewController

        newViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.toggleOnViewController(newViewController)
        self.currentViewController = newViewController

        // Set the delegate for the filter functions called by the cells in the collectionViewController filter menu.

    // Set the delegate for the filter functions called by the cells in the collectionViewController filter menu.

//Here is the line of code that fixes the problem...
        newViewController.filterDelegate = self

    filterMenuShowOn = true

    }


    // Hides filter menu scrolling bar from container view upon request.
    func hideFilterMenu() {

        currentViewController!.view.alpha = 1

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
            self.currentViewController!.view.alpha = 0
            },
                    completion: { finished in
                            self.currentViewController!.view.removeFromSuperview()
                            self.currentViewController!.removeFromParentViewController()
        })

    }
```

I want to thank Matt for getting me thinking about what was happening.